# Delete drupal content page

Tags: routes, nodes

How can one Delete Drupal content page (article/basic page) without actually visiting the page. Without Drush or visiting the database (which is a little complicated in D.7).

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. How could you interact with the system if you don't want to do with in neither browser, from cli, or directly in the DB? Magic? :)

Comment: You've alienated every possible method except for editing the binary db files manually. And you really don't want to do that. Can you explain why you can't use any of the proper methods?

Comment: @Clive No, no. I mean I will visit my site/use browser. Suppose there is NEWS basic page that I created. Now, I don't want to goto NEWS page. My home page is there. I can log in to system. I was expecting someway, there is some option in menus to delete the NEWS page without going to NEWS page itself. Or may be it is stored somewhere in site folder or somewhere. Guess I will have edit the database, can you suggest how to do it using if possible with phpmyadmin? I mean where are contents stored?

Comment: goto `admin/content` and press `delete` per page next to its title. You dont have to Edit the page. You will have to `confirm` your delete choice.

Comment: @tenken thanks! as stupid as one could possibly get. But it's fault of using slidedown menu module. Never thought it's there.

Comment: I have made my response into an answer if you care to accept it as the correct answer. this will better help others users by showing them the correct answer and not needing to riffle through all these comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

goto `admin/content` and press `delete` per page next to its title. You don't have to Edit the page. You will have to `confirm` your delete choice.